# Differences between normal forms

Tags: database, relational-database

I'm learning about normal forms and wonder, can a table be in multiple normal forms at once e.g. first and second?

From [here](http://www.andrewrollins.com/2009/08/11/database-normalization-first-second-and-third-normal-forms/) the definition of first normal form is "No repeating elements or groups of elements" and second is "No partial dependencies on a concatenated key" so it seems like this is possible. Also what is considered theoretically "the best"? For example is it better to have first normal form or Boyce-Codd normal form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the table is in the 3rd normal form for example it's automatically in all the lower forms. If the table fails to be in the 3rd normal form it means that it's in the 2nd normal form. For most of the tables it's enough to have 3rd normal form.

Comment: So not just the 3rd right? For example if it's in Boyce-Codd Normal Form it's automatically in 3,2,1 normal form?